# Manejar Errores de MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hola quiero ver si alguien me puede echar la mano con esto.

Quiero saber si al realizar una consulta en MySQL desde PHP me devuelva la razon del error o false en todo caso pero no se como hacer eso.

Tengo esto que me funciona bien, pero me surgió el detalle que al borrar ID`s si hay llaves foraneas en la Base de datos manda error, requiero que me regrese un "false" pero no se como hacerlo.

```
function ejecutarConsulta($query){
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($query);
    return $query;
  }
```

Si realizo la consulta desde MySQL directamente me regresa...

> #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zap`.`ven`, CONSTRAINT `fk_pro_has_ven1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `idc`) REFERENCES `producto` (`idp`, `idc`) ON UPDATE CASCAD)

He estado buscando y encontré esto pero no me regresa nada...

```
function ejecutarConsulta($query){
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($query);
    var_dump($query);
    if (!$conexion->query($query)) {
          printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
          printf("Error: %s\n", $conexion->error);
          printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
          
    }else{
      $query = $conexion->query($query);
      return $query;
    }
  }
```

Los 3 printf no los pongo juntos todos voy uno por uno para ver cual funciona pero no me regresa nada.

Comment: donde conseguiste ese codigo???

Answer (score 0):

Podés configurar a `mysqli` para que lance excepciones utilizando [`mysqli_report`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php), así si la consulta falla, utilizando [`try/catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) capturas la excepción y manejas los errores a gusto.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
// Activamos todos los errores
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

// ...
function ejecutarConsulta($query)
{
    global $conexion;
    try {
        return $conexion->query($query);
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        // echo $e->__toString();
        return false;
    }
}

//
$query = ejecutarConsulta('SELECT * FROM tabla');
if ($query === false) {
    echo $conexion->error;
    die();
}
```

---

**Observación:** El código que comparto es solo un ejemplo y con el mismo intento educar ni sobre buenas prácticas, POO o arquitecutra de software.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso no activo "estrictamente" los errores y aun así los manejo de la siguiente forma.

Sin Sentencias Preparadas (caso de este post)

```
public function queryFunction($sql){
    // Variable de la conexión
    $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
    // Quitamos espacios de inicio y final
    $sql = trim($sql);

    try {
        $result_set = $MySQLi->query($sql);
        $lastID = $MySQLi->insert_id;

        return array($result_set, $lastID);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Debugger
            echo '<br>Error en la Query';
            echo ': <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b>';
        return '';
        die();
    }
}
```

O mejor aun, con Sentencias Preparadas

```
public function queryFunction($sql, $paramsType, $params){
    // Variable de la conexión
    $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
    // Quitamos espacios de inicio y final
    $sql = trim($sql);

    try {
        $stmt = $MySQLi->prepare($sql);

        $bindParams = array($paramsType);
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $bindParams[] = &$params[$key];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bindParams);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result_set = $stmt->get_result();

        $lastID = $MySQLi->insert_id;

        return array($result_set, $lastID);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Debugger
            echo '<br>Error en la Query';
            echo ': <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b>';
        return '';
        die();
    }
}
```

Ahora, los echo los manejo tanto para usuarios como para desarrolladores, esto quiere decir que si yo quiero ver el error exacto, activo el debugger que tiene la línea `$e->getMessage()` y muestra todo y sino, al usuario solo le muestra un texto sin información técnica.

Los errores del debugger (para desarrollo) se ven así

[image: Error]

Y para los mortales, se ven así

[image: Error]